# Настройка SSL сертификата для Ngrok. Telegram-bot на C#

Tags: c#, ssl, telegram-bot, telegram, netsh

Я хочу написать Telegram Bota на C#, используя WebHook. Я воспользовался сервисом Ngrok, который выдает https-адрес, и будет перенаправлять пакеты на локальную машину. Делаю все так на написано в примере бота [здесь](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.WebHook/Program.cs).

```
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("https://+:8443"))
        {
            // Register WebHook
            Bot.Api.SetWebhook("https://1234eeee.ngrok.io/WebHook").Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Server Started");

            // Stop Server after <Enter>
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Unregister WebHook
            Bot.Api.SetWebhook().Wait();
        }
```

Перед этим я настраиваю порт с помощью команд:

```
> netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:8443/ user=Все
> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8443 certhash=<cert thumbprint> appid=<random guid>
```

Делаю это так, как написано в [этой](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/103396/) статье.
И указываю в certhash=‎53e6c6860a403880ad77703a8b6d4bd1d4dcc451.
Однако при выполнении второй команды, получаю ошибку:

```
> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8441 certhash=53e6c6860a403880ad77703a8b6d4bd1d4dcc451 appid={44127caa-e8de-4292-9a3a-b2dc25948c27}

Сбой добавления сертификата SSL. Ошибка: 1312
Указанный сеанс работы не существует.  Возможно, он уже  завершен.
```

В чем моя ошибка? И какая правильная последовательность действий для настройки сертификата? Может быть существует другой способ для создания сертификата? И что именно нужно указывать в параметре appid?

Comment: во-первых - *For the moment, the only supported port for Webhooks is 443. We may support additional ports later*

Comment: c 443 тоже самое, сейчас исправлю вопрос

Comment: где то же самое? с 8443 или с 443?

Comment: и с 8443 и с 443 портом не работает